# Convexity of a set defined by integrals of a function on measurable sets

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

While studying measurable function, I want to know if the following statement is true. Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb R^n$ with a support with nonempty interior, $f$ polynomial function and $B$ a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ : $$A = \left\{\int_{\Omega} f \mathrm d\mu : \Omega \subset B \text{ $\mu$-measurable}\right\}$$ is convex. Can any one help me to prove or disprove this statement ?

Comment: Is the measure assumed to be a Borel measure?

Comment: Can't one take a measure with discrete support? E.g. $\mu(H):=|H\cap\{0,1\}|$ on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: If you add this assumption could you prove it

Comment: @Berci, I add a codition on $\mu$.